# Highcharts fill bubble on hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm making a combination chart using Highcharts.js.

It consists of a line and two series of bubbles - one to indicate positive changes, and one to indicate negative.

My code looks like:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: false,
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: false,
                    labels: {
                        enabled: false,
                    },
                    gridLineWidth: 0
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer'
                    },
                    bubble: {
                        minSize: 50,
                        maxSize: 80
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Line',
                    data: [{"y":7,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":6.9,"color":"#BF0B23"},{"y":9.5,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":14.5,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":18.2,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":21.5,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":25.2,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":26.5,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":23.3,"color":"#BF0B23"},{"y":18.3,"color":"#BF0B23"},{"y":13.9,"color":"#BF0B23"},{"y":9.6,"color":"#BF0B23"}],
                    showInLegend: false,
                    marker: {radius: 18},
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false,
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'Positive',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        x:0,
                        formatter:function() {
                            return this.point.z;
                        },
                        style:{color:"black",fontSize:"16px",textShadow:"0px"}
                    },
                    type: 'bubble',
                    color: '#0BBF23',
                    data: [{"x":2,"y":9.5,"z":2.6},{"x":3,"y":14.5,"z":5},{"x":4,"y":18.2,"z":3.7},{"x":5,"y":21.5,"z":3.3},{"x":6,"y":25.2,"z":3.7},{"x":7,"y":26.5,"z":1.3}],
                }, {
                    name: 'Negative',
                    type: 'bubble',
                    color: '#BF0B23',
                    data: [[1,6.9,0.1],[8,23.3,3.2],[9,18.3,5],[10,13.9,4.4],[11,9.6,4.3]],
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        x:0,
                        formatter:function() {
                            return this.point.z;
                        },
                        style:{color:"black",fontSize:"16px",textShadow:"0px"}
                    },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            halo: {
                                size: 1,
                                attributes: {
                                    zIndex: 9000
                                },
                                opacity: 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    pointWidth: 1,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    showInLegend: false,
                    data: [{"y":7,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":6.9,"color":"#BF0B23"},{"y":9.5,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":14.5,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":18.2,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":21.5,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":25.2,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":26.5,"color":"#0BBF23"},{"y":23.3,"color":"#BF0B23"},{"y":18.3,"color":"#BF0B23"},{"y":13.9,"color":"#BF0B23"},{"y":9.6,"color":"#BF0B23"}]                }]
            });
```

As you can see I'm using the "halo" to try to fill in the bubble on the negative series when it's hovered. Ideally I'd like to increase the bubble size and font as well, but I have no clue how to make it happen.

Does anyone have any idea how to make the marker fill with solid colour, increase radius and increase font size on hover?

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/18qa8rds/1/

It's worth noting that on my local version the line plot shows through the halo, but it doesn't on the fiddle.

Comment: You might want to make a JS.Fiddle with a working example of your code. it may make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: thanks for the tip crazymatt

Comment: typical - one of the issues I'm facing doesn't happen in the fiddle - but I still can't get the text to resize to fill the bubble marker

Comment: increase radius - make size = 20

Comment: Thsnks Anatoli, that's what I want to do. How?

Comment: Well, in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover) you won't find anything to update font size. Solution may be to use [mouseOver](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver) event and update point there. And update again on `mouseOut`. Regarding working in the jsFiddle - update Highcharts to 4.1.1.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I tried but couldn't figure out how to get at the point to change the radius. the only object I get in mouseOver has the data, but not the bubble marker

Comment: Also pawel - I'm getting the latest highcharts in the same way the docs do - what prompted to suggest I upgrade? Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Could you show live demo what you tried? Simply `this.update( new_options )` should be enough. Regarding upgrading - if you have the same version of Highcharts, the same version of jQuery etc. and still something doesn't work on your localhost, but works in the jsfiddle.. then sorry, but something must be different.

Comment: Pawel - now I understand what you meant about upgrading - my local version was indeed a little behind. Thanks for that. The z-index issue is fixed now.

I've tried using this.update in a mouseOver and although I can change the font size, changing "size" or "radius" has no effect on the bubble itself. Although I can play with the halo to achieve a visibly larger circle, the clickable area of the bubble remains at the same size, making it hard to click.

Comment: Could you post live demo? I will check that. Note: to change radius/size for the bubble, you should update `z` value.

Comment: Thanks Pawel - the currently linked fiddle has an example. The bubbleHovered method changes size, to a ridiculous one, but the radius stays the same. Changing z changes the value of z for the label too! I just want to make the clickable bubble larger and display the same number, but larger.